# Collaborate on a github-hosted markdown file, no login required

Tags: markdown, collaboration, github-pages

I have my blog on GitHub Pages with Jekyll. The .md files are in a public GitHub repo. I would like to be able to add a link at the bottom of a post, something like "Feedback? Suggest changes at `link`". This link would go to an interface that non-technical people can use to edit the .md file *without an account*. Bonus points if it can submit their changes as a pull request. But any way of storing the changes would be fine.

I've already tried to make this work with prose.io and stackedit, but it didn't work.

Comment: This would probably require an external app that has a GitHub user that can fork, branch, commit and push changes and then open a PR on your original repository (or just branch directly in the repository). I don't think anyone has created that yet. I like the idea!